# Node IPC Sibling Processes Communication

Tags: architecture, server, node.js

Assume the following architecture context:

```
                                               +-----------------------------+                                       
                   Lobby Server Starts Process |                             |                                       
 +--------------+                              |  Network I/O process        |                                       
 |              +------------------------------>                             |  Client I/O     +--------------------+
 | Lobby Server |                              |                             <----------------->                    |
 |              |                              +---------------^-------------+                 | Client Application |
 ++-----+-------+                                              |                               |                    |
  |     |                                                      |                               |                    |
  |     |                                                      |                               |                    |
  |     |                                     +-----------------------------+   Client I/O     |                    |
  |     |       Lobby Server Starts Process   |                |            <------------------>                    |
  |     |                                     | Another Network|I/O Process |                  +--------------------+
  |     +------------------------------------->                |            |                                        
  |                                           +-----^-----------------------+                                        
  |                                                 |          |                                                     
  |                                                 |          |                                                     
  |    Lobby Server Starts Process                I |        I |                                                     
  |                                               P |        P |                                                     
  +-------------------------------+               C |        C |                                                     
                                  |                 |          |                                                     
                                  |            +----v----------v-----------------------+                             
                                  |            |                                       |                             
                                  +------------>   Application Server Logic Process    |                             
                                               |                                       |                             
                                               +---------------------------------------+
```

My question is, given the following design, what are good ways to implement the communication between the Network I/O servers and the logic server. The logic server cannot depend on a specific network I/O process to work, e.g if a Network I/O process goes down for some reason the logic process must continue to function. All Network I/O processes and the logic process are child processes of the Lobby Server Process.

Essentially I am asking for ideas on how to implement the communication between sibling processes(Network I/O and Logic Server). This is all written in Node, if there is a specific solution for Node, but a general idea would be helpful too.

This is a follow up on [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/89531/should-a-socket-server-and-game-server-be-separate-processes)  question.

PS: I am sorry if this is too general of a programming question and doesn't belong here. If this is the case I will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most scalable solution, in my opinion, would be [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) with this binding for [Node](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node). ZeroMQ is a powerful implementation of the "sockets" concept whose communications backend can vary, so that it can be used equally well locally and remotely.